# Where I can find Apksigner tool?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, sign

I need to sign my game in unity V2 signing scheme, but I don´t know how. Somebody here tell me that I have to do it with apksigner, but I don´t know how, I look for some tutorials, but they aleready have some tool, which I haven´t. Can somebody please help me with it ?

Comment: It likely installs with the android sdk, probably in the tools folder.  Googled it and found the docs [APK Signer](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner)

Answer (score 0):

it's inside `sdk/build-tools/{version}/apksigner`

in macos you can find here

`/Users/{user}/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/{version}/apksigner`